# OCR, placing recognized text on camera view

Tags: android, tesseract

I am trying to print the recognized text on the camera view. I am getting this error:

Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I done some research about this problem, but even though i can not fox it probably because of luck of experience (first time I try to build an app using openCV and tesseract, I am encountering many errors i have not seen before). Please be lenient. My piece of the code in which i want to use Toast is added below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import android.os.Environment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

public class justOCR {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    protected Context context;

    public justOCR(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

        public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sdcard/CameraTest/";
        private static final String lang = null;

    public void numPlateOCR(Mat plate){ 

        bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(plate.width(), plate.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        org.opencv.android.Utils.matToBitmap(plate, bitmap);
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
        //byteArray = byteArray.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);


    // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

    Log.v("baseApi", "Before baseApi");

    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    //baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
    baseApi.init("/sdcard/CameraTest/", "eng");
    baseApi.setVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "1234567890");
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);



    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

    baseApi.end();

    // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with it.
    // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it (if lang is eng)
    // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

    Log.v("NUMBER", "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);

    //if ( lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ) {
    //  recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
    //}

    recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();

    if ( recognizedText.length() != 0 ) {
        //TODO print or save to xml//

        Toast.makeText(this.context, "***"+recognizedText+"***", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't know the answer but great question.

Comment: That error means you're running this on a thread which doesn't have a looper set up, but you made a call which requires one.  Probably yhe makeText call.  What thread are you on when you call this?  Have you tried running the makeText call on the UI thread?

Comment: i have a thread on which all processing (openCV) and tesseract works. How to use this looper? any example basing on my code? thanks you very much

Comment: I suggest fixing the indentation in your code to make it more readable. Also, go back and accept answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a Toast not on UIThread, another guy says it.

But look this, is important for u: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)